# How do I disable password complexity in pam

Tags: linux, authentication, pam, cracklib

I found tons of articles how to enable password complexity, can someone guide me to how to disable it? (oracle linux)

This is my system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
#password    requisite     pam_passwdqc.so min=N0,disabled,12,8,7 retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
#password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=1 sha512

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

commenting out pam_cracklib.so or changing the arguments, just break pam and make it impossible to use passwd at all. Thanks

Comment: How about trying to uncomment the "#password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so minlen=1 sha512" part and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM module pam_cracklib is responsible for testing password for complexity. configure like below.

```
#password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok 
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
```